# How to add custom text before the price in the header cart in Storefront theme woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

i want to add the text "Your Cart: " before the pricing in the header cart of storefront theme, i tried editing and adding it in inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php line 72 in

```
 <?php
function storefront_cart_link() {
<span class="amount">ADDED HERE<?php echo "AND HERE ALSO" . wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> 
}?>
```

though it appears on the frontend until site loads, when loading completes, the text just vanishes.
please suggest how to do it.

running WP v4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will display **Your Cart** Text if you add it outside anchor tag like below.

```
function storefront_cart_link() {
        ?>
            <span style="float:left;">Your Cart :</span> 
            <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
                <span class="amount"><?php echo wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?></span> <span class="count"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'storefront' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
            </a>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Thank @Jatin for the answer, it worked good on desktop, but on mobile devices, Your Cart: Text appears on the header, how to hide it on mobile devices.

Comment: you can add class you like and then use media queries to hide it in mobile device.
`<span class="cart_text">Your Cart :</span>`

so its css will be like this in normal screen 
`.cart_text{float:left;}`

and for mobile devices you can use it like this.
`@media (max-width:768px){.cart_text{display:none;}}`

add above line of code at the end of woocommerce.css which is located at : storefront\assets\sass\woocommerce\woocommerce.css

and it will work perfectly fine for mobile and desktop screen :)